# how to integrate $\mathrm{arcsin}\left(x^{15}\right)$?

Tags: integration, special-functions, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Integral by parts:
$$
I = x\sin^{-1}\left(x^{15}\right) - \int\frac{15x^{15}}{\sqrt{1-x^{30}}}dx
$$
then what?
The answer by wolfram gives an answer contains hypergeometric ${}_2F_1$ function,because it has no elementary answer. The question I want to know is, how can we find the integral of 
$$
\frac{15x^{15}}{\sqrt{1-x^{30}}}
$$
in terms of hypergeometric function?

Comment: yes,it is the function you write.

Comment: Not that I have tried, but I would guess you just substitute $t=-x^{30}$ in the Maclaurin series for $(1+t)^{-1/2}$, and then integrate termwise.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Lucian: I could, but a better answer was just posted anyway, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

$\int\dfrac{15x^{15}}{\sqrt{1-x^{30}}}dx$

$=\int_0^x15t^{15}(1-t^{30})^{-\frac{1}{2}}~dt+C$

$=\int_0^{x^{30}}15t^\frac{1}{2}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}~d(t^\frac{1}{30})+C$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^{30}}t^{-\frac{7}{15}}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}~dt+C$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1(x^{30}t)^{-\frac{7}{15}}(1-x^{30}t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}~d(x^{30}t)+C$

$=\dfrac{x^{16}}{2}\int_0^1t^{-\frac{7}{15}}(1-x^{30}t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}~dt+C$

$=\dfrac{15x^{16}}{16}~_2F_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{8}{15};\dfrac{23}{15};x^{30}\right)+C$

Comment: Comment added just for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Integral_formulas